# Enumerating over base with foreach

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I'm trying to do this in a class extending another class, which implements `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public override IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator(){
    foreach (var item in base){
        // Some logic here
        yield return item;
        // Some more logic here
    }
}
```

However this fails with compile error stating that "base" is used incorrectly.

I want to inherit all behaviour of the parent class except of inserting some "virtual" items into the enumerated collection and skipping some other items.

I worked around this by manually manipulating the enumerator (essentially doing what `foreach` expands to except calling `GetEnumerator` on `base` instead of `this`). But this doesn't result in exactly the most straightforward code.

So my question is: **Can this be done with foreach?**

Comment: If you want this behavior you could try casting this to the base type (assuming you know it). Like, if type base type is BaseType you could try foreach(var item in this as BaseType).

Comment: @Vlad How would this help when GetEnumerator is virtual? (all interface method implementations are virtual by default)

Comment: Right, that slipped my mind. How about using reflection to call the base GetEnumerator?

Comment: @Vlad I can call base.GetEnumerator() no problem - it actually does what I want it to do, but I then have to iterate over the collection using while(enumerator.GetNext()) etc., including all that IDisposable junk (which is normally hidden by the foreach). I would love to just use foreach and not have these 10 lines of ugly code. This question is out of curiosity (and about having a nice solution), I already have a working solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it can't be done with foreach.

There is big difference between `this` and `base` access in C#. When you use `this` keyword, it is classified as a value (type of value is the instance type of class where usage occurs). But `base` keyword is never treated as a value. It could be part of [base-access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691362%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) expression, which used to access base class members that are hidden by similarly named members in the current class:

```
   base.identifier 
   base[argument-list]
```

So, via `base` keyword you can only access members of base class. But it is not treated as value of base type, and it could not be part of expression where value used (e.g. casting, foreach statements, etc).

And only valid approach to do what you want is accessing members of base class:

```
public override IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    IEnumerator<T> enumerator = base.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        T item = enumerator.Current;
        // Some logic here
        yield return item;
        // Some more logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing. The code gets messier if you include the IDisposable stuff.